# ComponentService.createComponents(): 'callback' must be a Function pointer. : false

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, dynamic, javascript-controller

I want to be able to call $A.createComponents(type, attribute, calllback); with values in an array. SF doc I am following: [Dynamically Creating Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm). But the obvious value of this would be to populate an array and pass it to createComponents.

I am getting this error:

[image]

Here is the component:

```
    <aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="body" type="Aura.Component[]"/>

      {!v.body}

    </aura:component>
```

And the controller:

```
    ({
    doInit: function(cmp) {
debugger;
    var typeArray = ["ui:message","ui:message"];
    var objArray = [];
    var obj0 = {title:"Sample Thrown Error", closable:"true"};
    objArray.push(obj0);
    var obj1 = {title:"Sample Thrown Error1", closable:"true"};
    objArray.push(obj1);

        var finalInputs = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < typeArray.length; i++){
            var type = typeArray[i];
            var attributes = objArray[i];
            finalInputs.push([type, attributes]);
        }



   $A.createComponents(finalInputs,
    function(components, status, errorMessage){
        debugger;

        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            var cmps = components;
            cmp.set('v.body', cmps);
        }
        else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
            console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
            // Show offline error
        }
        else if (status === "ERROR") {
            console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
            // Show error message
        }
    }
);

    },
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely at the example provided in the developer docs, you'll see that the params for `$A.createComponents` are `[array,callback]` - specifically `([[][]...],function)`

Put your code in this format and you'll be ok.

Eg:

```
$A.createComponents([typeArray, objArray],
    function(components, status, errorMessage){
```

You mentioned that you were still having problems - looking at your code again, I can see that it has a further problem. In the example in the docs, you'll see that the structure of the code is quite different to what you have:

```
[
["ui:message",{
    "title" : "Sample Thrown Error",
    "severity" : "error",
}],
["ui:outputText",{
    "value" : e.message
}]
]
```

Generalising this you get:

```
$A.createComponents(
  [
    ["component1name",{"attributes1":"here"}],
    ["component2name",{"attributes2":"here"}]
  ],
  function()
);
```

Docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm#!)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you, but I am getting a similar error in regard to the js object being passed: Assertion Failed!: ComponentService.createComponent(): 'attributes' must be a valid Object. : false

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I have updated the code above with a working example for anyone to reference in the future.